# I want to display a image in UIImagaView tat image names stored in array .so how to get string from array in iphone

Tags: iphone

Actually i want to display iamge in UIImageView ...tat image names are getting from my database..so how to display image from getting string in an array in iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr_ArrayName objectAtIndex:index]];
NSString *path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *temp = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
yourImageView.image = temp;
```

Pass the index value as an integer which image from array you want to display.

**Edit:**

Declare one integer temp in your view will appear. Set it's value to 0. temp = 0;
Then, inside your button action please write the below mentioned code:

```
-(void)buttonClick
{
       NSString *selectedItem =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[colors objectAtIndex:temp]];
       NSString *wrdstr = [[ NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedItem ofType:@"png"];
       UIImage *temp = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:wrdstr];
       imgshow.image = temp;

       if(temp <= [colors count])
            temp = temp + 1;
}
```

Comment: now i got some codings but...in my project i set two buttons near imageview onebutton using for viewing previous image second button using for viewing next images ..i.e am using array na...so i got many results in images so viewing in like tis progress.....now while clicking 2nd button next image s not showing in ..so wat to do – raj just now

Comment: @raj Just increment the array index every time you click the button and pass it to the objectAtIndex as a parameter.

Comment: ya.i incremnt the loop to pass index..value..here its my coding

Comment: for(int i = 1; i<[colors count]; i++){
 NSString * selectedItem =[selectedItem stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[colors objectAtIndex:i]]];
 NSString* wrdstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",selectedItem];
 [imgshow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:wrdstr]];
 }

Comment: @raj:See i've edited my answer. Don't use the for loop as it'll be executed once and all. So u won't be able to see any images. You'll only see the last image. Does it help?

Comment: rushi thanks for ur information.....ya i got output...with help of my collegue....being u too guided me..tanks a lot rushi>>>>>>

Comment: atcually  i did a minor mistake then my collegue identified wat i done wrong nu.. and corrected coding by myself......

Answer (score 0):

use this methods

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
imageView.animationImages = animationImages ;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 2;
imageView.animationDuration= 4.0;
[imageView startAnimating];
```

animationImages is an Array containig UIImage Objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *imageNameStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:index]];

UIImageView *myImage;
myImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00.0, 00.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
myImage.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:imageNameStr];
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

hope it Help To you

Comment: now i got some codings but...in my project i set two buttons near imageview onebutton using for viewing previous image second button using for viewing next images ..i.e am using array na...so i got many results in images so viewing in like tis progress.....now while clicking 2nd button next image s not showing in ..so wat to do

Comment: Just increment the array index every time you click the button and pass it to the objectAtIndex as a parameter.

Comment: as Rushi say increment the index. set 2 condition one in nextBtn. if(index >=imageNameArray.count){ index = imageNameArray.count-1;} In BackBtn if (index <= 0){ index = 0;} so you can see Next Image and privies image on decrement index number.

Comment: for(int i = 1; i<[colors count]; i++){ NSString * selectedItem =[selectedItem stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[colors objectAtIndex:i]]]; NSString* wrdstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",selectedItem]; [imgshow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:wrdstr]]; }

Comment: this s my codingi which were given in action for showing next next images.....in my coding[colors] is NSMutablearray object...so using array am storing all valuesretrieved from database and displaying relevant iimages in image view....so kindly tel me any idea